# Finding "A" matrics, in inverse matrices

Tags: matrices

If a matrix A satisfies the equation $\ 7A^{-1} $ find A

$\ 7A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}-3&7\\1&-2\end{bmatrix} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7A$^{-1}$ = \begin{bmatrix}-3&7\\1&-2\end{bmatrix} =>A$^{-1}$= \begin{bmatrix}-3/7&7/7\\1/7&-2/7\end{bmatrix}. *The determinant D=(-3/7).(-2/7) - 1/7 = -1/49.*
I would let you proceed further from here on when you know that A X A$^{-1}$ = A$^{-1}$ X A = 1

Comment: You don't really need the determinant here, do you^^

Comment: If you compute A the long way.